# Help using tezos-node! Command not found

Tags: node

I can't use the `tezos-node` command. No matter what I try to do, `tezos-node: Command not found` is returned. I have double checked the location with `readlink -f tezos-node and I receive`/home/blakeyar/tezos-node`, so I know I am in the right location. Any ideas on how I can tezos-node commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I do is `./alphanet.sh shell`
once you have entered in shell mode, you can run `tezos-node`, `tezos-client`, etc